# A system error occurred: uv_os_gethostname returned ENOSYS (function not implemented) - sanity

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-7, sanity

SystemError [ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR]: A system error occurred: uv_os_gethostname returned ENOSYS (function not implemented)
at e.default (C:/node32/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:1908:2252)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async C:/node32/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:4890:2440
at async e.default (C:/node32/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:4890:2315)

When i try logging into the sanity through vs code terminal, this error shows up.
please tell me how to fix this thing?
can i login through site and connect it with my project manually?